# Rails Geocoder Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, function, rubygems, geocode

With the geocoder gem, if I wanted to find pictures nearby one particular picture by a mile I could do pictures.nearby(1) but what if I had a user with a location and wanted to find pictures nearby my user, how would I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nearby() you can use

```
Pictures.near([u.lat, u.lon], 1)    # venues within 1 miles of a user
```

See [GitHub/geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)